# What is the left side in a mysql join?

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say we have this query:

```
SELECT t1.* from t1
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t2.t1id = t1.id;
```

Sure it's a bad example but it get's my point across; What is considered the left side?
`t1` or `t2`? is it the *first selected table* or the *first table in the on clause* or something completely different?

I get the different joins thanks to [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) but I cannot find explained anywhere where the sides come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more obvious if you write it;

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t2.t1id = t1.id;
```

Essentially, `LEFT JOIN` indicates that *every row in the leftmost table `t1` is included*, matching rows in the rightmost table being optional, and `RIGHT JOIN` would indicate that *rows in the rightmost table `t2` are always included*, matching rows in the leftmost table being optional.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT side is the part where you want to include from, but not limit to if it does not exist.

[Have a look at this graphical representation of JOINS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Lets say you have

```
TABLE1 

ID

1
2
3
```

and

```
TABLE2

ID

2
3
4

SELECT *
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Would return

```
t1.ID   t2.ID
1       NULL
2       2
3       3

SELECT *
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Would return

```
t1.ID   t2.ID
2       2
3       3
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN
t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Would return

```
t1.ID   t2.ID
2       2
3       3
NULL    4
```

Answer (score 1):

`t2` is the "left side."  Essentially this says "select all records from `t1` where `t1.id` is equal to `t2.t2id` or `t2.t1id` does not exist.  If the "left side" condition does not exist (i.e. this was an inner join and not an outer (left) join), records where `t2.t1id = t1.id` would be required to exist.